# After changing to remote registry, admin services stop working in wso2 products, tried with esb, is, BAM

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

After changing to remote registry, admin services stop working in wso2 products, trie with esb, is, BAM.

tried

### http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Config+and+Governance+Partitions+in+a+Remote+Registry

as well as

### http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Config+and+Governance+Partitions+in+Separate+Nodes

Comment: 1. This fails with no offset or offset in carbon.xml. I was suspecting that this might be failing because of offset.

Comment: 2. on Mgtm console after login when i try to follow ' 'Service Bus -> Sequences' i get following error.[2013-07-04 15:04:18,847] ERROR - SequenceAdminClient Couldn't retrieve the information of the sequences
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) local://services/SequenceAdminService

Comment: Was able to resolve this. Do not keep same cluster name for different products when you are enabling the tribesclustering.

Answer (score 0):

Seems some thing missing in document.

I was able to resolve this issue by updating the domain thing based on the product and did not kept it wso2.carbon.domain as is by default.

for e.g

```
<parameter name="domain">wso2.esb.domain</parameter>
```

this solved my problem and i am running all WSO2 products this way.